# What happens if there is an error in the CRC code itself for a signal?

Tags: signals, crc, data-transfer, telecommunication, crc16

We using crc algorithm to detect errors , and we send with our message crc code , but what happened if an error occurre when we send it ? And how we detected?

I try nothing to do , but i guess that we will not get a 0 in the reciver,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in the appended CRC are detected in the same way, with the same efficacy, as errors in the message.

The combined message+CRC is a codeword, which has some minimum distance, measured in the number of flipped bits, to nearby codewords. One less than that distance is the number of erroneous bits that can be assuredly detected.